# Mercurial: roll back a patch?

Tags: mercurial

I was trying to create a patch for review. I should have done `$ diff -u oldfile newfile > tiny.patch`, but instead I did `hg qnew 404.patch`.

Now my log looks like this:

```
changeset:   2913:82fc6e8ec5aa
tag:         404.patch
tag:         qbase
tag:         qtip
tag:         tip
user:        xxxxxx
date:        Fri Sep 23 12:09:53 2011 +0100
summary:     [mq]: 404.patch

changeset:   2912:87e6ed84fe2f
tag:         qparent
user:        xxxxxx
date:        Fri Sep 23 10:45:10 2011 +0100
summary:     Change that I want to keep
```

How can I get rid of the top changeset? I mean delete, kill, remove from history - I just don't want it in the log.

`hg rollback` gives me `no rollback information available`.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `hg revert` the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run

```
hg qpop -a
```

To pop off the unwanted patch, then

```
hg qdelete 404.patch
```

to delete it, then start again.

Comment: Thanks. `hg qpop 404.patch` returns `qpop: 404.patch is already at the top`. And `hg qelete 404.patch` returns `hg: unknown command 'qelete'`!

Comment: Just tried: `hg qdelete 404.patch` but get `abort: cannot delete applied patch 404.patch`.

Comment: Ah OK figured it out: `hg qpop -f` to pop, then `hg qdelete 404.patch`. Phew! Thanks!